# How do I determine that this point is optimal?

Tags: linear-programming

I have one  linear programming problem given by
\begin{matrix}{}
      \min   & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^I c_ix_i ; &c_i\geq 0\\
      &\\
        s.a &  \sum_{i=1}^{I}x_i=d,& d\geq0\\
        &\\
        &0\leq x_i\leq b_i& 1\leq i\leq I
    \end{matrix}
Where $c_i$ are parameter that indicates cost.

I have determined that this problem has an optimal solution if and only if $d\leq b_1+b_2+\cdots b_I$.

And since the coefficients are positive, then this problem can be solved by placing as much of the decision variable $x_i$ as possible, from the lowest cost to the highest cost , and so on until the sum is $ d $. But I can't mathematically formulate this fact, i mean, i want to show that if I take another $ x $ in the feasible region then the value given by this point will be less than the point generated by the process mentioned above.
Example of the processe
\begin{matrix}{}
      \min   & 5x_1+3x_2+x_3 ; &\\
      &\\
        s.a &  x_1+x_2+x_3=800& \\
        &\\
        &0\leq x_1\leq 400&\\
&\\
&0\leq x_2\leq 200\\
&\\
&0\leq x_3\leq 500\\
    \end{matrix}
the variable associated with the lowest cost is $ x_3 $, so to minimize the objetive function i put $x_3=500$ (the maximum possible), then $x_2$ is the next with $x_2=200$, so at this point i have $700$ and i only need 100 more to obtain 800, then $x_1=100$. Thus the optimal point is $(100,200,500)$.

How do I show that if I choose another point this can't be optimal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two alternative approaches to prove optimality:

1. Show that for any other feasible solution, you can perturb it to improve the objective value while preserving feasibility.
2. Find a dual feasible solution that certifies optimality of your primal solution.